# getLocalBounds alternative for Text Objects? (SFML)

Tags: c++, user-interface, sprite, sfml

Trying to make buttons using SFML for Comp Sci final and really don't want to draw invisible sprites over every single button.

I found some solutions but they were all using older versions of sfml and those functions have since been removed or changed and not sure what they've been changed to.

```cpp
while(window.isOpen()){
        Event event;

            while(window.pollEvent(event)){

                switch(event.type)
                {

                    case Event::Closed:
                        window.close();
                        cout << "Window Closed!" << endl;
                        break;

                    case Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                        if(event.mouseButton.button == Mouse::Left){
                            cout << "  if(event.mouseButton.button == Mouse::Left){" << endl;
                            if(equationsButtonText.getLocalBounds().contains(event.mouseButton.x, event.mouseButton.y)){
                                cout << "This works!" << endl;
                                }
                            }

                    default:
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

> cout << "  if(event.mouseButton.button == Mouse::Left){" << endl; was just to test how far into the loop it got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getLocalBounds` returns the bounds in the local coordinates of the text. You need to use `getGlobalBounds` to get it in world coordinates.

You also need to use the `mapPixelToCoords` method of your window to transform the coordinates of the mouse also to world coordinates.

It would be something like this:

```
if(equationsButtonText.getGlobalBounds().contains(window.mapPixelToCoords({event.mouseButton.x, event.mouseButton.y}))){
    cout << "This works!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to send myself the .cpp file from school so i'll check tomorrow but, 
1. getGlobalBounds I believe gave me a error about FloatRect
2. Not using a view either

Comment: Both functions return FloatRect so if you use it the same, it should not emit any error. If you use the default view then you can omit mapPixelToCoords.

Comment: if(equationsButtonText.getGlobalBounds().contains(window.mapPixelToCoords({event.mouseButton.x, event.mouseButton.y})))

Im not sure why it works but it does. Thanks a lot!